# How to generate a unique id and save it to mongoDB in passportJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I am using passportJS, in my callback I would like to carry the following operations.

1) generate a random string

2) check the database if that id exists, if it exist then regenrate id untill it is unique.

3) Save the user model (with a unique id).

I tried writing multiple functions but it seems that the `newUser` object is undefined inside the functions!

Here is my functions I am using from my mongoose model.

```js
userSchema.methods.generateVci = function(length, characters){
    var string = '';
    for(var i = length; i > 0; --i){
        string += characters[Math.round(Math.random() * (characters.length - 1))];
    }
    return string;
};

userSchema.statics.validateVci = function(uniquekey){
    this.find({}, function(err,user){
        for(var i = 0; i < user.length; ++i){
            var uservci = user[i].local.vci;
            if(uservci == uniquekey){
                console.log('false');
                return false;
            }
        }
        console.log('true');
      return true;
});
};
```

```js
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                
                // check to see if theres already a user with that email
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
                } else {





                        var generatedVciKey = newUser.generateVci(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

                        var isvalidvci = User.validateVci(generatedVciKey);

                        if(isvalidvci){
                            var newUser = new User();
                            newUser.local.email    = email;
                            newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                            newUser.local.vci = generatedVciKey;
                        }


                    // save the user
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }

            });

        }));
```

If you could please show me a way to write some sort of recursive function in that passportjs would only save the user model when a unique ( checked with the database) id has been generated. The unique id must be regenerated again and again until it is truly unique from any other ids in the database. I have no clue how to do this as it seems that when I write a function the variables in the passportjs callback becomes undefined.

Comment: The `_id` property that MongoDB will generate for your document will be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote this generateVci but you should really use node-uuid like someone already suggested

```
userSchema.methods.generateVci = function(length, characters) {
  return characters.split('').map(function() {
    var randomKey = Math.round(Math.random() * (characters.length - 1));

    return characters[randomKey];
  }).join('').substring(0, length);
};
```

Your validateVCI is async so you have to pass a callback or other way is to use promises

```
userSchema.statics.validateVci = function(uniquekey, cb){
  this.find({}, function(err, users){
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }

    var isInvalid = users.reduce(function(invalid, user) {
      if (invalid) {
        return true;
      }

      return user.local.vci === uniquekey;
    }, false);

    if (isInvalid) {
      return cb(null, false);
    }

    console.log('true');
    return cb(null, true);
  });
};
```

You should make vci field unique in your database ...
So when you try to create a user with same vci it would fail

```
function createUser(email, password, done) {
  var generatedVciKey = newUser.generateVci(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

  User.validateVci(generatedVciKey, function(isInvalid) {
    if (isInvalid) {
      return createUser(email, password, done)
    }

    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.local.email    = email;
    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
    newUser.local.vci = generatedVciKey;

    // save the user, or try again on error
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return createUser(email, password, done);
      }

      done(null, newUser);
    });
  });
}

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            }

      createUser(email, password, done);
    });
}));
```

Comment: please answer that question, really not sure what it does.

Comment: Its doing the same you did, going trought all users and checking if there is already used vci, instead of doing this you could just update the query for find method :)

Comment: ok, is it a mongoose built in function? where would `invalid` parameter ever be returned as true? Just don't see the logic.

Comment: It would be true the first time this becomes true user.local.vci === uniquekey, you should check reduce documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Do you realy need to do this? You can use [node-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uuid) to generate unique identifier. So the probability that you will generate non-uniqe id negligible low